# Amazon DynamoDB Item Size?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm just exploring the whole NoSQL concept. I've been playing around with Amazons DynamoDB and I really like the concept. However that said I am not quite sure how the data should be separated. By this I mean should I create a new Table for related data features like you would in a relational database or do I use a single table to store all the applications data?

As an example, in a relational DB I might have a table called users and a table called users_details. I would then for example, create a 1:1 relationship between the two tables. With the NoSQL concept I could theoretically create two tables as well but it strikes me as more efficient to have all the data in a single table.

If that is the case then when do you stop? Is the idea to store all the application data for a given user in a single table?

Answer (score 0):

First ask yourself: why did I separate the users from the user details in RDBMS in the first place. 
 
On a more general note, when talking about NoSQL you really shouldn't look at relationships between tables.
 You shouldn't think about "joining" information from different tables but rather prepare your data in a way that can be retrieved optimally.
In the user/user_details scenario, put all information in a users table, and query what you want by specifying the attributes to get.